# Output filename when building Nuitka module

Tags: python, nuitka

Previously I used Python 3.6 and Nuitka 0.6.7 to build a Nuitka module, the output filename is **test_module.pyd**
then I upgraded to Python 3.9 and Nuitka 0.9, and the output filename is now **test_module.cp39-win32.pyd**. I want to remove **.cp39-win32** in the filename. I read through Nuitka --help, but I can't find the command to modify it.
Here is the command I used to build Nuitka module

```
python -m nuitka --module some_module.py --mingw64 --no-pyi-file --remove-output
```

Any help is appreciated